# What does it mean if the weapon type text is in red?

Tags: diablo-iii

What does the red weapon type mean, "Rare Staff"?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tooltips highlight, in red, the attribute of the item that disqualifies your character from wielding it. So, since the type is highlighted, that means that your character cannot wield Staves.

Comment: damn. i was hoping it meant it was really good or something :)

Comment: There should be an X on the item picture in that case, no?

Comment: I think it's generally accepted that red = bad.

Comment: @fbueckert only on the icon in your inventory.

Comment: The X only appears for class-specific items that are not for your class, I think